# How to apply a method to a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe

```
   Col1              Col2

0  A (1000 EUR)  C ( 3000 USD)

1  B (2000 CHF)  D ( 4000 GBP)
```

I would like to convert it to

```
   Col1  Col2

0  1000  3000

1  2000  4000
```

I know how to create a dataframe (with indexes) for 1 column, but not for multiple columns

This code produces this result

```
   Col1

0  1000

1  2000 

a = z['Col1'].str.split('(').str[-1].str.split().str[0].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')
```

how can I amend the code above to also add col2 (ideally using vectorisation rather than iteration) (so ideally I wouln't want to have to enter the same code for every column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function to apply your operation to all elements in both rows.

```
# creates your dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['A (1000 EUR)','B (2000 CHF)'], 'Col2':['C (3000 USD)', 'D (4000 GBP)']})

# use the apply function to  apply your code to all elements of both columns
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('(').str[-1].str.split().str[0].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce'))
```

Does the trick for me

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) on each column and use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to build a new dataframe from the result:

```
x = np.concatenate([df[col].str.extract(r'(?<=\()\s*(\d+)') for col in df], axis=1)
pd.DataFrame(x, columns=df.columns)

   Col1  Col2
0  1000  3000
1  2000  4000
```

Comment: dont need apply here. Agree on that.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [df.applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html). The difference from `df.apply` is that `df.apply` takes a whole series (row or column) as an argument and applies a function where `df.applymap` takes every element of the DataFrame and applies a function. Try this:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(str(x).split('(')[1].split()[0], errors='coerce'))
```

print(df)

```
   Col1  Col2
0  1000  3000
1  2000  4000
```

df.info()

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Col1    2 non-null int64
Col2    2 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(2)
memory usage: 48.0 bytes
None
```

Comment: very interesting, like this one too. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `applymap` method of a pandas dataframe. It would look something like:

```
import re

function_to_apply = lambda x: re.search("[0-9]+", x).group()
your_dataframe.applymap(function_to_apply)
```

Possible something like that would work in your case, and would certainly be a bit simpler!

Comment: I like what you did there with `re`. You do need to use `df.applymap` in this case, though! See my answer above.

Comment: Thanks, and good catch, I will edit accordingly!